# Find difference b/w avg salary of departments

Tags: sql

[image: department table image]

Find difference b/w avg salary of departments?

```
select avg(sal) as a from employee where dept = 'SC'
MINUS/-
select avg(sal) as b from employee where dept = 'DP'
```

these sql queries donot seem to work!

Comment: Please check the tags again. Are you really using both, MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: The reason you are getting downvotes is because you have posted an image of your table instead of DDL and sample data, this link will help you to post better quality questions in the future:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MINUS` is the set minus operator in Oracle and is called `EXCEPT` in SQL Server and doesn't seem to exist in MySQL (at least I couldn't find it). But you don't seem to want a set minus but an arithmetic minus. Try

```
SELECT (SELECT avg(sal)
               FROM employee
               WHERE dept = 'SC')
       -
       (SELECT avg(sal)
               FROM employee
               WHERE dept = 'DP');
```

which should work both in MySQL and SQL Server. (Unless you completely tagged at random and are not even using one of these.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `CASE` to get the rows you want:

### DDL

```
create table t (
  Dept char(2),
  sal int
  )

  insert t (dept, sal)
  values('aa', 1234),
  ('aa', 1234),
  ('bb', 5432),
  ('bb', 4321)
```

### Answer

```
select avg(case when dept = 'aa' then sal else null end) - avg(case when dept = 'bb' then sal else null end)
from t
```

This will only require a single scan of your table, so should be faster than the subquery route.